# Solving a set of nonlinear equations

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I am trying to setup and solve a set of nonlinear equations. I keep getting an error. Here is my problem:

```
sol = 
  NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == -z[t] [x[t] + 1.5 Log[z[t]]],
                y'[t] == z[t] - 1,z'[t] == -(.64) [y[t] + (x[t] + Log[z[t]])/.8]

ParametricPlot[{sol,{t,0,1000}, AxesLabel{"y[t]","z[t]"}]
```

Any help would be highly appreciated ......

Answer (score 4):

This works

```
Clear[x, y, z]
sol = NDSolve[Join[
    Thread[{x'[t], y'[t], z'[t]} == {-z[t] x[t] + 1.5 Log[z[t]], 
       z[t] - 1, -(0.64) y[t] + (x[t] + Log[z[t]])/0.8}],
    Thread[{x[0], y[0], z[0]} == {1, 1, 1}]], {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 100}];

ParametricPlot3D[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 100}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use square brackets for parentheses and must include initial conditions.

```
eqns = {
     x'[t] == -z[t] (x[t] + 1.5 Log[z[t]]),
     y'[t] == z[t] - 1,
     z'[t] == -(.64) (y[t] + (x[t] + Log[z[t]])/.8),
     x[0] == y[0] == z[0] == 1} //
    Rationalize // Simplify;

sol = NDSolveValue[eqns,
   {x[t], y[t], z[t]}, {t, 0, 1000}];

Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot3D[sol, {t, 0, tmax},
  AxesLabel -> {"x[t]", "y[t]", "z[t]"},
  ColorFunction -> (Hue[#4] &)],
 {{tmax, 50}, 10, 1000, 10,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False]
```

[image]

If you want the 2D plot of {y[t], z[t]}

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[Rest[sol], {t, 0, tmax},
  FrameLabel -> {"y[t]", "z[t]"},
  Frame -> True,
  Axes -> False,
  ColorFunction -> (Hue[#3] &)],
 {{tmax, 50}, 10, 1000, 10,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False]
```

[image]